# How to update a nested state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to update customize inside subcatagory

```
constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                name: '',
                subCatagory: [{ name: '', price: '', customize: [] }],
            };
        }
```

my form look like this

```
{this.state.subCatagory.map((subCatagory, idx) => (
                    <div className="subCatagory" key={idx}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={`Enter Dish  #${idx + 1} name`}
                            value={subCatagory.name}
                            onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryNameChange(idx)}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            placeholder={`subCatagory #${idx + 1} price`}
                            value={subCatagory.price}
                            onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryPriceChange(idx)}
                        />
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={this.handleRemovesubCatagory(idx)}
                            className="small"
                        >
                            Delete
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" onClick={this.addNewCust(idx)} className="small">
                            is cust availble?
                        </button>
                        {subCatagory.customize.map((gj, idx) => (
                            <div key={idx}>
                                <input
                                    type="number"
                                    placeholder={`subCatagory #${idx + 1} price`}
                                    value={gj.name}
                                    onChange={this.gjj(idx)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                ))}
```

how to update the inner json value using react onChange ., is there way to update model in react.js usnig es6 ?

Comment: what is this.gjj "onChange={this.gjj(idx)}".  You defined "gj" inside the map function. I think it's a typo

Comment: function to get the value from input

Comment: ok whats the error you getting?

Comment: can't able to update the customize value

Comment: can you add your gjj function as well. Is it properly binded.

Comment: `gjj = idx => evt => {
  console.log(idx)
 };`

Comment: i can't able to get the parent index so if i get the parent index then  i can update the json

Comment: wait i"ll post jsfiddle link